# Laravel 5 Auth middleware works after csrf in post requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have group of routes, that need to be protected by Auth middleware. I use standard Auth filter.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('....', '....');
    Route::post('....', '....');
    ...
```

It works fine with GET requests, but when I do POST-request I see Token Mismatch Exception. I think, CSRF middleware work before Auth. How to change order of these filters? I need to see Unauthorized exceptions to make redirect from ajax-requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `app/Http/Kernel.php`, there is declaration for the web middleware. Change the order accordingly or you can disabled it temporarily to debug the code

The web middleware group includes the `VerifyCsrfToken::class` to prevent from CSRF injection to the POST request. If you include the csrf_token during the POST request in the form, the form mismatch error should be resolved.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

Answer (score 0):

What i get from your question the problem is when you send the POST Form. So in laravel post form requires an token security.
Write this one inside of your request form for example

```
<form method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
     blah blah blah ...
   </form>
```

after this try to send request and would work fine